# How can I calculate today's date ONLY if today is less than or equal to the last day of the current month in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to express the following expression in Google Sheets:

IF today's date is less than or equal to the last day of the current month (in this case October 2021), THEN output today's date, OTHERWISE output the last day of the month (i.e. October 31, 2021)

I've tried a few different ways but nothing seems to work. Below is my latest attempt, but I get an #ERROR.

```
=IF(TODAY(<=2021,10,31),TODAY(),DATE(2021,10,31))
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I guess your dates are in column B then try in cell              C2 = If(B2<>Now(), B2, Now())

Answer (score 0):

You need `EOMONTH()` function. Try below formula-

```
=IF(TODAY()<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),TODAY(),EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
```

[image]

Comment: `TODAY()<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)` this will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `=TODAY()`. if you are interested in **current** month.

If you need today's date, but not further then the last day of October, use:

```
=MIN(TODAY(), DATE(2021, 10, 31))
```